# HTML anchor tags don't work in child window FF/IE only

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

If I open a window (window.open()) and put HTML in it that includes an anchor and a tag the anchor will not navigate to the tag in FF. It does work in Chrome. Notice the following HTML which puts the same HTML in both the parent and child. The parent works correctly (makes the jump inside the document) but the child does not. Note that we're not jumping between parent and child, both HTML function 100% independently. Make sure to shrink the parent window so you can see the anchor working.

```
<html>
<bead>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function popBob() {
            newwin = window.open("", "_blank", "width=800,height=200,scrollbars=1");
            var myhtml= '<html><div><a href="#bob">click me!</a><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><a id="bob"/>you made it!!</div></html>';

            $('html').html(myhtml);
            $(newwin.document.body).html(myhtml);

        }
    </script>

</bead>
<body onload="popBob()">
</body>
</html>
```